# Can't downcast after `storyboard.instantiateViewController`

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `storyboard.instantiateViewController` to start a TableViewController, but when I try to downcast it, I get an error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x109b30de8) to 'PresenceTableViewController' (0x1060329f0).
```

My class PresenceTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController, and the storyboard has assigned the VC class correctly. [image]

So why would this fail?

```
presenceViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userPresenceTable") as! PresenceTableViewController
```

Comment: Are you sure you use right storyboard? which is store userPresenceTable.

Comment: @KamaniJasmin I only have 1 storyboard. Main.storyboard

Comment: Your `presenceViewController` object is declared as UITableViewController like var `presenceViewController:UITableviewController` ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya "presenceViewController" is the property name in the VC that's holding the table. I have a InfoViewController, that has a section with two tabs, each load a different VC. The actual controller that is loaded is like this: `class PresenceTableViewController: UITableViewController`

Comment: You should declare  `presenceViewController` as `PresenceTableViewController` not UITableViewController

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya What do you mean? `presenceViewController` is just the variable name that stores the instance. The class model name is `PresenceTableViewController`. `UITableViewController` is the class PresenceTVC inherits from. What are you suggesting I change?

Comment: Just show how you declare object

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya This is how it is declared `class PresenceTableViewController: UITableViewController {`

Comment: @PeterR I am not asking how you declare class  how you declare property !!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya It's in the post above. `presenceViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userPresenceTable") as! PresenceTableViewController`

Comment: @PeterR There is var or let missing !!!! in your question so it seems to be a global object to me.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya At the top it's like this `var presenceViewController: PresenceTableViewController!`

Comment: @PeterR Yes that's what i was asking !! and  is it  compile time error ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya No, runtime error. It fails when I try to downcast.

Comment: @PeterR You should put all info. in question. by seeing this it seems to compile time error . No worries try below solution should work for you. it happens when you copy paste viewcontroller into storyboard

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I did put the error in the question. The error even has runtime object addresses. How can you think it was compile time? `Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x109b30de8) to 'PresenceTableViewController' (0x1060329f0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the possible cases for "Could not cast value..." and it was woking fine for all cases, and then I generated this error in one case when module was not inherited from target. This solved the problem for me.

> Just re-enter the class type on storyboard, it will automatically select "Inherit module from target". This would solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Yes, If will uncheck `Inherit module from target` + remove module and compile it, same error appears - @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: This was it! I knew it was something like this. I'm not sure why this happened, as I've never had to manually check that box before, it always just works.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that your controller from you want to use must be embed  with navigation bar

```
 let tableviewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableviewController") as! tableviewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableviewController, animated: true)
```

[image]